# Python injection

Tags: python, dependency-injection

i am in the current situation. I have a Service class, which uses a Logic component, which uses a Storage object.

So:

Service ---> Logic ---> Storage

The arrows represent a 'uses' relation.

Of course i am trying to use dependency injection, and i am using the `injector` package (https://github.com/alecthomas/injector).

The objective here is to have different versions of the Service instances, which will be using different Logic instances, that differ in the Storage instance used.

I think it's something that is presented [here](http://injector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/practices.html#injecting-dependencies-only-to-pass-them-somewhere-else).

Now, the point is the following: i have not understood how to apply injection to several levels. Here's a little example:

```
from injector import inject, Injector, Module, Key

# My example
# Standard service using a ConsumerLogic which is requesting a Storage object


class Storage:
    pass


class Storage2:
    pass


class Logic:

    def __init__(self, storage):
        self.storage = storage


class Service:
    def __init__(self, logic):
        self.logic = logic
```

By using the BoundedKey class, i have worked something out:

```
from injector import inject, Injector, Module, Key

# My example
# Standard service using a ConsumerLogic which is requesting a Storage object


LogicKey = Key('Logic')


class Storage:
    pass


class Storage2:
    pass


class Logic:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, storage: Storage):
        self.storage = storage


class Service:
    @inject(logic=LogicKey)
    def __init__(self, logic):
        self.logic = logic


class Configuration(Module):

    def configure(self, binder):
        binder.bind(
            LogicKey,
            to=Logic(storage=Storage())
        )
```

And to use the service instace i can do:

```
inj = Injector()
inj.get(Service)
```

obtaining that specific version of the service.

How can I make the `get` method to return me different version of the Service ? I have not been able to work out something with Module approach. But i must be missing something.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Why do you need injection for this? Just pass the instance you want to the constructor you want and everything will be configured the way you want it. There is no need to get all enterprisey unless you have a real use case.

Comment: It's an extract from a Kafka consumer designed with an hexagonal architecture to 1) decouple the logic of the consumer from the boilerplate to have the consumer running and 2) make it easily extensible so that you can still use the consumer infrastructure and just provide new adapters for the IStorage interface. To give you a very quick explanation, of course.

Comment: Quick is fine. Important thing is that you understand why you need it.

Comment: I agree. Also, I am strongly separating the framework layer from the application layer, and DI would be really helpful with this.